# Custom validation function not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

my serializers.py:

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(
        style={'input_type': 'password'},
        required=True
        )
    remember_me = serializers.BooleanField(required=True)
    temp_code = serializers.HiddenField(default='0')

    def validate_login(self):
        username = self.data["username"]
        if not username:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('username must not be blank!')
        self.temp_code=1
        elif len(username) < 6:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('username must create atleast 6 characters!')
        self.temp_code=2
        return value
```

I above have a serializer by which I'm getting user credentials for Login. I want to set unique code values with `'temp_code'` which I can access in my LoginView. On basis of that I'll perform some operations in the view.

I'm trying with the above code and also all tricks I got in other questions but unfortunately it's not woking.

Can anybody please suggest me the correct approach to do so.

Thanks! in Advance

Comment: Are you calling `validate_login()` explicitly because without a `login` field in the serializer, it won't be called

Comment: You also shouldn't be referencing `self.data` before the object is saved. In future versions of DRF, this may trigger an exception.